# An upper bound to $\mathbb{P}[|\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \mu)| > \epsilon n] $

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

Let $\epsilon > 0, \, (X_i)_{i\geq1}$ be a sequence of identically distributed (we denote $EX_i$ by $\mu$) and pairwise (not mutually!) independent random variables

prove that there exists some constants $C$ such that:

$\mathbb{P}[|\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \mu)| > \epsilon n] \leq C(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}[|X_i|>n]+\mathbb{P}[|\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)\mathbb{I}_{\{|X_i| \leq n\}}|>\frac{\epsilon n}{2}])$

this inequality was used in the second part of a math paper I was reading, I've been trying to prove it for the last couple of days but to no avail, if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Is the factor $1/2$ in the last probability important?

Comment: @Michh not for the rest of the proof, after that Markov's inequality is used and that factor just merges with the C, paper doi is : 10.1007/s10474-013-0370-4 btw, it's lemma 2.1 second part of the proof if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
$$\begin{multline*}\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu) \right|>\epsilon n\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu) \right|>\epsilon n, \, |X_i| >n \text{ for some } i\right) \\+ \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu) \right|>\epsilon n, \, |X_i|\leq n \text{ for every } i\right).\end{multline*}$$
The first term is less than $\mathbb{P}(|X_i| > n \text{ for some } i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(|X_i|>n)$. The second term is equal to
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu) \mathbf{1}_{|X_i|\leq n}\right|>\epsilon n, \, |X_i|\leq n \text{ for every } i\right) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu) 
\mathbf{1}_{|X_i|\leq n}\right|>\epsilon n\right)$$
which proves your inequality.

Comment: very nice ! I just realized that the complimentary set turns every "for some" into "for every" and vice versa, I wasn't doing that switch, thanks!